# Given matrix P such that $P^{102 } =0 $ , to show that $P^{2} = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

P is given to be a 2×2 matrix such that $P^{102} = 0$. How to show that $P^{2} =0 $?

Comment: May I presume you haven't yet studied Jordan Canonical Form? Perhaps eigenvalues, eigenvectors...?

Comment: @Timbuc well you may not

Comment: Ok, then piece of cake, @godonichia: the only eigenvalue of $\;P\;$ is *obviously zero*, so $\;P\;$  is either the zero matrix or one which is similar to $\;\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\;$ . Solve now your problem.

Comment: @Timbuc ok i havegot it . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the JCF of your matrix: since it obviously has zero as it only eigenvalue, the matrix is either the zero one or else similar to

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

In either case, it is immediate that $\;P^2=0\;$ .

Answer (score 5):

Let $s=\min\{k\in\Bbb N\mid P^k=0\}$. There's $x_0$ such that $P^{s-1}x_0\ne0$ and then $(x_0,Px_0,\ldots, P^{s-1}x_0)$ are linearly independent vectors. In fact if $\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_{s-1}\in\Bbb R$ such that

$$\alpha_0 x_0+\alpha_1 Px_0+\cdots+\alpha_{s-1}P^{s-1}x_0=0$$
then applying $P^{s-1}, P^{s-2},\ldots,P^2$ respectively to the last equality we get $\alpha_i=0$ and since the dimension is $2$ then $s\le2$. We conclude that $A^2=0$.

Comment: Thanks for answer , a different way of doing thisqueston

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

What is the rank of $P$? What are the eigenvalues of $P^2$?

**More Hints**

Let $f$ be the linear application associated to $P$. If rank of $P$ is $2$ then $f$ is surjective and $f^{102}$ is also surjective and $P^{102}\neq 0$. So the rank of $P$ is not $2$.

If the rank of $P$ is $0$ then $P=0$ and $P^2=0$.

If the rank of $P$ is $1$ then $E$, the image of $f$, has dimension $1$. If $f(E)=E$ then $f^{102}(E)=f^{101}(E)=E$, so $P^{102}\neq 0$ We deduce that $f(E)$ is not $E$. Since $E$ has dimension $1$ then $f(E)$ has dimension $0$, that is, $f(E)=\{0\}$ or $f^2=0$

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Comment: You last paragraph is the way to go on this problem imo. Simpler than Jordan canonical forms etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach with no need to refer to eigenvalues or Jordan normal form:

Note that $\operatorname{range}(P)\supseteq\operatorname{range}(P^2)\supseteq\operatorname{range}(P^3)\supseteq\cdots$. If one of those inclusions is an equality, then all the subsequent ones are also equalities. But a $2\times2$ matrix must have rank equal to $2$, $1$, or $0$, so there is room for only two strict inequalities in the series. Thus $\operatorname{range}P^2=\operatorname{range}P^{102}$.

The unproved claim above boils down to this: If $\operatorname{range}P^{n}=\operatorname{range}P^{n+1}$, then $\operatorname{range}P^{n+1}=\operatorname{range}P^{n+2}$. This follows because $\operatorname{range}P^{n+1}=P(\operatorname{range}P^{n})$ and $\operatorname{range}P^{n+2}=P(\operatorname{range}P^{n+1})$.

Comment: This is the way I see the question as well. It seems the simplest and most basic way of looking at the situation.

Answer (score 1):

What do you know about [nilpotent matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix#Characterization)? More particularly, are you familiar with [Cayley—Hamilton's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)?
(if so, observing that all eigenvalues of $N$'s characteristic polynomial $\chi_N$ must be zero, what can you say about $\chi_N$?)

Comment: Nilpotent matrices have trace 0 .characteristic polynomial of form A^n .

Comment: Nilpotent matrices have only one eigenvalue, which is zero (why?). CH Theorem: $\chi_N(N)=0$. Characteristic polynomial: the (complex) root of $\chi_N(N)$ are exactly the eigenvalues of $N$, and $\chi_N$ has degree $n=2$.

Comment: Thankyou forhelp i see now

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers already, so I'll not try to add a high-level approach, but instead give a completely *ad hoc* approach. Let subspaces $R,N$ be the range an null space of $P$. Distinguish two cases

1. $R\cap N=\{0\}$. Then $P$ defines a map $R\to R$ that is injective (its kernel is $R\cap N$), so $P^{102}=0$ implies that $R=\{0\}$ so that in fact $P=0$; then of course $P^2=0$ too.
2. If $R\cap N\neq\{0\}$, then since $\dim(R)+\dim(N)=2$ by rank nullity, one has $R=N$; so $P^2=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $P$ is nilpotent because of $P^{102}=0$. Because $P$ is a $2\times 2$-matrix, it must satisfy either $P=0$ or $P^2=0$. But if $P=0$, then $P^2=0$ follows immediately.

Note, that the minimal polynomial must be either $x$ or $x^2$.

Comment: Well, I think the question is **exactly** why "it must satisfy either..." !